# libSVM for iOS?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Has anybody been able to compile libSVM for iOS? I haven't found any guide online, or anybody reporting how fast it is on the new devices. Could anybody point me to the right directions in order to get libSVM running on iOS (if that's possible at all)?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What issues are you running into?

Comment: I haven't tried libSVM on the iOS yet. Before I start I would like to find some documentation about it. I am sure I'm not the first one who's trying to do this, so I was hoping to find somebody here to point me towards the right directions.

Comment: If you're just looking for this thing to compile, Xcode can do it.  It says it has a C++ head on it, so it's no problem.

Comment: Thanks @CodaFi, I guess after I tweak the code or point to the right libraries on XCode I will be able to compile libSVM (it's in C after all). But I wanted to know if somebody had experience with it. Or maybe somebody has already tried it and they found is not fast enough on the device.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [SVM](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html) included in [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/table_of_content_ios/table_of_content_ios.html)? OpenCV has recently added support for iOS and its SVM implementation it's actually based on LibSVM.It is the best option I have found for implementing easily SVM on iOS.